# Prove this identity...

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{\sin 2x}{1+\cos 2x} \times \frac{\cos x}{1+\cos x}=\tan\frac{x}{2}$$
This is what I've done:
$$\frac{2\sin x \cos x}{1+\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x} \times \frac{\cos x}{1+\cos x}=$$
$$\frac{2\sin x \cos x}{2\cos^2 x} \times \frac{\cos x}{1+\cos x}=$$
$$\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}$$
I have no idea what to do next.

edit:
Solution:

$$\frac{\sin2\frac{x}{2}}{1+\cos2\frac{x}{2}}=$$
$$\frac{2\sin\frac{x}{2}cos\frac{x}{2}}{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}+\cos^2\frac{x}{2}+\cos^2\frac{x}{2}-\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}=$$
$$\frac{2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}}{2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}=$$
$$\frac{\sin\frac{x}{2}}{\cos\frac{x}{2}}=\tan\frac{x}{2}$$

Comment: The $\frac{x}{2}$ in the answer should provide a clue. In your last step, there is still no hint of $\frac{x}{2}$. How will you change $x$ to $\frac{x}{2}$?

Comment: First, you should use \sin and \cos, not sin and cos. As to your question, do you know the half-angle identities? One form of the half-angle identity for $\tan$ is $\tan\frac{x}{2} = \frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}$.

Comment: @M.Vinay Thanks, I'm dumb... xD

Comment: @A6Tech Thanks, but there are some answers here already, you should accept one of them :)

Comment: @M.Vinay But you helped me, so I want your answer accepted. I'll upvote their answers.

Comment: $\dfrac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}= \tan\dfrac x 2$ is one of the standard tangent half-angle identities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\cos 2\theta = 2\cos^2 \theta - 1 \Rightarrow 1 + \cos 2\theta = 2\cos^2 \theta$. Therefore:

$$\dfrac{\sin 2x}{1 + \cos 2x} \times \dfrac{\cos x}{1 + \cos x}\\
= \dfrac{\not 2\sin x \not\cos x}{\not 2 \not\cos^2 x} \times \dfrac{\not\cos x}{2 \cos^2 (x/2)}\\
= \dfrac{\not 2\sin(x/2)\not\cos(x/2)}{\not 2\cos^{\not 2} (x/2)}\\
= \boxed{\tan \dfrac{x}{2}}
$$

*Note: In the above, the $\not\square$s denote cancellations.*

Answer (score 4):

By your estimate we have  $$\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}=\frac{2\sin \frac{x}{2}\cos \frac{x}{2}}{2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}=\tan\frac{x}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}=\frac{\sin 2\frac{x}{2}}{1+\cos 2\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{2 \sin (\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2})}{1+\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})-\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})}$$